# If Contains "Text" Return "Number"

Tags: formula-field, contains

I'm trying to create formula field which returns 1 when text field CONTAINS certain text, else 0.
E.g. if text field "City" CONTAINS NY or New York or NewYork, then it should return 1 else 0.

I'm able to achieve this using EQUALS as follows. But I want to use CONTAINS.
**Can someone please help, how to use CONTAINS or any other solution that searches particular text within a text field and returns NUMBER?**

```
if (City= "NY" || City = "New York" || City = "NewYork", 1, 0)
```

I tried this as well but it gives error "Incorrect number of parameters for function 'if()'. Expected 3, received 5".

```
if (CONTAINS(City,"NY"),CONTAINS(City,"New York"),CONTAINS(City,"NewYork"),1,0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a combination of `OR` and `IF` like this.

```
if (OR(CONTAINS(City,"NY"),CONTAINS(City,"New York"),CONTAINS(City,"NewYork")),1,0)
```

Here your `IF` logic will be calculated on `OR` basis and if you City has any one of the three text, it will result in `true` and return 1, orelse 0.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution worked Nagendra Singh.

Answer (score 0):

Can anyone help to correct this , if my code snippet is wrong:
I am using Contains keyword in Classic HTML Email Templates, i need to display dynamic values based on if Condition inside myCar();
example: myCar(MARUTHI 156);

myCar({!IF(CONTAINS(Case.Engine_Model_Db__c ,"MARUTHI")),"MARUTHI 156","{!IF(CONTAINS(Case.Engine_Model_Db__c,"SWIFT")),"SWIFT A1","False"}"})

Thanks in Advance
sfdclearner

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! This is a Questions & Answers site, not a threaded forum. Please see the various pertinent/relevant notes in [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers), and be aware that your "answer" will likely be deleted. You could ask a [new question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), and in it you can link to this question or its other answer for reference (just click "Share" at the bottom left of the post to get a URL).

Answer (score -1):

Can anyone please help me to solve this problem. I have a website field in accounts page layout where i wanted to eliminate if website contains either "HTTP" or "WWW" or numbers 0-9 or special characters through the validation rule. Request you to please help!

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/187988)